# Class variable does not maintain its value in onCreateDialog

Tags: android, arraylist, android-dialogfragment

I have made a DialogFragment helper class for all dialogfragments I have in
my app. I also have an arraylist of unknown type (generics ) that gets its 
value depending on which activity a static arraylist is coming from. In 
order to distinguish the activity the static arraylist is coming from, I use
a boolean class variable. To my surprise this boolean variable, although
gets its value in newInstance(Context c, int dialogNumber) method, in 
onCreateDialog method it gets the default boolean value, which is false.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here's the DialogFragmentHelper class' code:

```
public class DialogFragmentHelper extends DialogFragment {

private static final ArrayList<FoodRecord> allRecords = FoodActivity.allRecords;
private static final ArrayList<BgRecord> mBgRecords = MainActivity.mBgRecords;
private static ArrayList<?> mRecords;
private int dNumber;
private Context mContext;
private boolean fromFoodActivity;


public DialogFragmentHelper newInstance(Context context, int dialogNumber) {
    mContext = context;
    if(mContext instanceof FoodActivity || mContext instanceof FoodExpandableListActivity) {
        fromFoodActivity = true;
        mRecords = allRecords;
    }
    else {
        fromFoodActivity = false;
        mRecords = mBgRecords;
    }
    DialogFragmentHelper mDialogFragment = new DialogFragmentHelper();

    // Supply dialogNumber input as an argument
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DIALOG_NUMBER_KEY, dialogNumber);
    mDialogFragment.setArguments(args);

    return mDialogFragment;
}


// Build AlertDialog using AlertDialog.Builder
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dNumber = getArguments().getInt(DIALOG_NUMBER_KEY);

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    Button okButton;
    Button cancelButton;


    switch(dNumber) {
    case CHOOSE_DATES_DIALOG_FULL_HISTORY:
        if(mRecords != null && mRecords.size() != 0) {
            adb.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_dates_dialog, null))
            .setCancelable(true)
            .create();

            AlertDialog customChooseDialog = adb.show();
            if(fromFoodActivity) { //here fromFoodActivity is false
                TextView mTitle = (TextView) customChooseDialog.findViewById(R.id.title);
                mTitle.setText(R.string.food_activity_log);
            }
        }
     ....    
     }
```

From the respective activities I call the DialogFragmentHelper class this way:

```
DialogFragmentHelper af = new DialogFragmentHelper();
mDialog = af.newInstance(this, CHOOSE_DATES_DIALOG);
mDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Choose");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because inside `newInstance()` method you create a completely new instance of `DialogFragmentHelper` whose default value of `fromFoodActivity` is `false`.

The whole construction is a bit wicked. "Helpers" are usually needed to get access to the main object, but here a helper helps create a helper.

Anyway, as a quick fix you can set `fromFoodActivity` for this new instance:

`mDialogFragment.fromFoodActivity = fromFoodActivity;`

Comment: Good answer! I now understand my mistake. But, how should this helper class be?

Comment: @Nick thank you, happy to help. To some extent it's a matter of a personal choice, but in this case I would rename the class so there's no "helper" in it (because it's misleading), make `newInstance()` static (because it's a coding pattern called "Static Factory" and it only makes sense when it's static; it being an instance method is what caused the error in the first place). That's pretty much it. In this case you can use it as `mDialog = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(this, CHOOSE_DATES_DIALOG)` and set all private fields inside the method, during creation.

Comment: Good point. I am bit afraid of too much "static-ness" because static methods communicate only with static variables and this may cause problems in case you want to communicate with non static methods. Anyway I did it your way ...